# ElasticSearch AngularJS Client - when i include space in search result is not correct

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch.I found that when I search with "2" it gives following record but when I search "2 liter" it gives empty result. It seems that ElasticSearch Server is not considering space between words.

*suso orange quality flavour in 2 liter can ERP2*

Can anybody please help me that what I need to change ?

Thank You.

**One Field in my indexed JSON**

Product Detail : suso orange quality flavour in 2 liter can ERP2

**ElasticSearch AngularJS Client code.**

```
EsConnector.controller('QueryController', function($scope, es) {
 $scope.change = function() {
console.log($scope.searchProduct);

// search for documents
    es.search({
    index: 'test_index',
    size: 50,
    body: {
    "query":
        {
            "regexp": {

               "productDetail":$scope.searchProduct+".*",
            } ,
            "analyzer": "whitespace"
        },
    }

    }).then(function (response) {
      $scope.hits = response.hits.hits;
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use simple query string request, not regexp; change query to $scope.searchProduct+"*".
2. "Whitespace analyzer" breaks your query into terms on whitespace - it means, elasticsearch will look up documents with terms "suso" and "orange" for query string "suso orange".
3. Another important thing you didn't mention is index analyzer; it's the setting which tells elasticsearch how to break your document fields on terms it woll later be searching and how to "preprocess" them - for instance, lowercase or change one symbols to another.